C++ mockup of AHK's ControlSend not working
I recently wanted to make a function that sends a input to a window (in this case a key press) similar to AHK's ControlSend function.
Each attempt of mine run fine without exceptions but the key was not pressed as it would be if I was using ControlSend from ahk.
I tried:
        SendMessageA(this->window, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x41, 0);
        Sleep(10);
        PostMessageA(this->window, WM_KEYUP, 0x41, 0);
// 0x41 = "A"

,
// this one was pretty much ripped straight from ahk's github 
    LPARAM lParam = (LPARAM)(0x1E << 16);
    HWND aTargetWindow = FindWindowA("Notepad", NULL") 
    WPARAM aVK = 0x41;
    PostMessage(aTargetWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, aVK, lParam | 0x00000001);
    PostMessage(aTargetWindow, WM_KEYUP, aVK, lParam | 0xC0000001);

// this one was some old code i used in a older project which did work at the time but just decided to stop working now 

            // Send the key down message
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0);

            // Small delay to ensure the key up message is recognized
            Sleep(10);

            // Send the key up message
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0);
                
            Sleep(sleep);
            

In all instances I tested on notepad and confirmed that I properly got the hwnd.
Incase this helps for whatever reason here is an ahk script that DOES work and has the expected behavior (just with L instead of A)
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 

windowTitle = Untitled - Notepad 

WinWait, %windowTitle%
if WinExist(windowTitle)
{
    ControlSend,, L, %windowTitle% ; Send the "L" key to the window
}
else
{
    MsgBox, Window not found 
}

My expected result is for it to be able to send key presses, clicks, etc to whatever window without having it in the foreground (this I know is possible due to AHK's ControlSend & ControlClick additionally the third code block also used to work just shit itself for whatever reason.)
Any help will be appreciated and please request any more info if needed.

You can't simulate keyboard input with Postmessage

You can't simulate keyboard input with Postmessage, use SendInput instead. The MSDN website has an example.
Quote of the blog post:

Some people attempt to simulate keyboard input to an application by posting keyboard input messages, but this is not reliable for many reasons. First of all, keyboard input is a more complicated matter than those who imprinted on the English keyboard realize. Languages with accent marks have dead keys, Far East languages have a variety of Input Method Editors, and I have no idea how complex script languages handle input. There’s more to typing a character than just pressing a key. Second, even if you manage to post the input messages into the target window’s queue, that doesn’t update the keyboard shift states. When the code behind the window calls the GetKeyState function or the GetAsyncKeyState function, it’s going to see the “real” shift state and not the fake state that your posted messages have generated.
The SendInput function was designed for injecting input into Windows. If you use that function, then at least the shift states will be reported correctly. (I can’t help you with the complex input problem, though.)

The following types "d" in Notepad on my machine:
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"

void TypeD()
{
    INPUT inputs[2] = {};
    ZeroMemory(inputs, sizeof(inputs));

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = 'D';

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = 'D';
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    UINT uSent = SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
}

PROCESS_INFORMATION RunNotepad()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    wchar_t cmdLine[] = L"notepad";
    if (!CreateProcess(nullptr, cmdLine, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%ld).\n", GetLastError());
        return pi;
    }
    while (!FindWindow(L"Notepad", nullptr)) Sleep(1);
    return pi;
}

int main()
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = RunNotepad();
    HWND notepad = FindWindow(L"Notepad", nullptr);
    if (notepad == nullptr)
        return 0;
    if (!SetForegroundWindow(notepad))
        return 0;
    TypeD();


    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}

